# React + Redux + oidc

Tags: redux, openid-connect, redux-toolkit

I have problems when I try add oidc provider in index.tsx
I use React with Redux Toolkit.

I have this code in other project. It works fine there.
I try change dependencies from my work project, but it didn't do anything.
Projects differ only in dependency versions.

index.tsx

```
root.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <OidcProvider store={store} userManager={userManager}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <App />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </OidcProvider>
    </Provider>,
)
```

```
OidcProvider -> error -> 
TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(props: OidcProviderProps<CombinedState<{ oidc: UserState; notify: INotifys; }>> | Readonly<OidcProviderProps<CombinedState<{ oidc: UserState; notify: INotifys; }>>>): OidcProvider<...>', gave the following error.     Type '{ children: Element; store: ToolkitStore<CombinedState<{ oidc: UserState; notify: INotifys; }>, AnyAction | Action<User | Error>, [...]>; userManager: UserManager; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<OidcProvider<CombinedState<{ oidc: UserState; notify: INotifys; }>>> & Readonly<...>'.       Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<OidcProvider<CombinedState<{ oidc: UserState; notify: INotifys; }>>> & Readonly<...>'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(props: OidcProviderProps<CombinedState<{ oidc: UserState; notify: INotifys; }>>, context: any): OidcProvider<CombinedState<{ oidc: UserState; notify: INotifys; }>>', gave the following error.     Type '{ children: Element; store: ToolkitStore<CombinedState<{ oidc: UserState; notify: INotifys; }>, AnyAction | Action<User | Error>, [...]>; userManager: UserManager; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<OidcProvider<CombinedState<{ oidc: UserState; notify: INotifys; }>>> & Readonly<...>'.       Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<OidcProvider<CombinedState<{ oidc: UserState; notify: INotifys; }>>> & Readonly<...>'.
```

store.ts

```
import {configureStore} from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import {loadUser} from "redux-oidc"

import {rootReducer} from "./rootReducer"
import {userManager} from "../config/userManager"

const loadUserDefault = () => {
    userManager
        .clearStaleState()
        .then(() => loadUser(store, userManager))
        .catch((err) => console.error(err))
}

export function customConfigureStore() {
    const store = configureStore({
        reducer: rootReducer,
    })

    loadUserDefault()

    return store
}

export const store = customConfigureStore()

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

userManager.ts

```
import {
    UserManager,
    UserManagerSettings,
    WebStorageStateStore,
} from "oidc-client"

import {pathsList} from "./pathList"

const uri = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}${
    window.location.port ? `:${window.location.port}` : ""
}`

const userManagerConfig: UserManagerSettings = {
    /**
     other my code
    **/
    loadUserInfo: true,
    userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({store: localStorage}),

    includeIdTokenInSilentRenew: true,
    monitorSession: false,
}

export const userManager = new UserManager(userManagerConfig)
```

packeg.json

```
***
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.2",
    "antd": "^5.2.1",
    "axios": "^1.3.2",
    "oidc-client": "^1.11.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.43.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-oidc": "^4.0.0-beta1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2"
***
```

What could be the problem?